# Calculate execution time of all the function

Tags: c, performance, time

This project has many functions which some of them takes a lot of time to execute. **Now my task is to find those functions which tasks the most of time.**

Here is my steps:

1. Write a macro to calculate execution time

   ```
   #ifndef _CALCULATE_EXE_TIME_
   #define _CALCULATE_EXE_TIME_

   #include <time.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   #define CALCULATE_EXE_TIME static clock_t CET_start_time, CET_end_time; \
   static float CET_expend_time, CET_total_expend_time;            \
   static unsigned int CET_invoked_times = 0;                      \
   CET_start_time = clock();                                       \

   #define CET_BEFORE_RETURN CET_end_time = clock(); \
   CET_expend_time = (float)(CET_end_time - CET_start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; \
   CET_total_expend_time += CET_expend_time;                       \
   printf("===%s:%s()  invoked_times=%u  expend_time=%.4fs  total_expend_time=%.4fs\n", \
          __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, ++CET_invoked_times, CET_expend_time, CET_total_expend_time);

   #endif  // _CALCULATE_EXE_TIME_
   ```

2.Put the macros to all the functions

```
static void john_register_one(struct fmt_main *format)
{
    CALCULATE_EXE_TIME

    // Do something   

    CET_BEFORE_RETURN
}

many other functions
many other functions

static char *john_loaded_counts(void)
{
    CALCULATE_EXE_TIME

    static char s_loaded_counts[80];

    if (database.password_count == 1) {
        CET_BEFORE_RETURN return "1 password hash";
    }

    CET_BEFORE_RETURN return s_loaded_counts;
}
```

3. Run

   ```
   ===wordlist.c:mgetl()  invoked_times=1893  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0082s
   ===cracker.c:crk_process_key()  invoked_times=1880  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0097s
   ===cracker.c:crk_process_event()  invoked_times=10  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0011s
   ===cracker.c:crk_password_loop()  invoked_times=235  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=208.5752s
   ===cracker.c:crk_salt_loop()  invoked_times=235  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=208.6260s
   ===cracker.c:crk_done()  invoked_times=1  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0000s
   ===wordlist.c:get_progress()  invoked_times=2  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0000s
   ===wordlist.c:save_state()  invoked_times=2  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0000s
   ===wordlist.c:do_wordlist_crack()  invoked_times=1  expend_time=208.9100s  total_expend_time=208.9100s
   ===batch.c:do_wordlist_pass()  invoked_times=1  expend_time=208.9100s  total_expend_time=208.9100s
   ===batch.c:do_batch_crack()  invoked_times=1  expend_time=208.9109s  total_expend_time=208.9109s
   ===wordlist.c:get_progress()  invoked_times=3  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0000s
   ===cracker.c:crk_get_key2()  invoked_times=1  expend_time=0.0000s  total_expend_time=0.0000s
   ```

**HERE is my questions**:

I have to put the CALCULATE_EXE_TIME and CET_BEFORE_RETURN to **all the functions manually**! It's a huge work! **Is there any way to do it automatically**?

I have thought put the CET_BEFORE_RETURN to the destructors so that it can be invoked after the function returns. But gcc does not support class destructor.

Comment: Try `#define return CET_BEFORE_RETURN return`

Comment: If you are on a Unix system, you can use `gprof`. Compile your code with `-pg` option, run it and type `gprof ./a.out`.

Comment: @iharob  Thanks, it does help me. But in this case, if (1==something) return 1; I want it can be replaced as if (1 == something) **{** CET_BEFORE_RETURN return; **}**. **The brace should be added**

Comment: @loverszhaokai there is also [valgrind](www.valgrind.org) which has the `callgrind` tool, and there are graphical interfaces for it too, which are very helpful.

Comment: @iharob Thanks a lot. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a profile tool, like VTune for VS or Instruments for Xcode so that you don't need to add the ugly code to calculate execution time, which can also slow down execution and make your results less accurate. Profiling tools provide more information，such as locating performance bottlenecks.